# Converting Output of a Map Function to String in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to update a script that generates strings so that it can run on Python 3. Here's the troublesome snippet:

```
from itertools import islice, repeat
from os import urandom
import string

string_len = 16
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation   

char_gen = (c for c in map(urandom, repeat(1)) if c in chars)
pswd_text = ''.join(islice(char_gen, None, string_len))
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting a TypeError:

```
% python3 ./string_generator.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./string_generator.py", line 12, in <module>
    pswd_text = ''.join(islice(char_gen, None, pswd_len))
  File "./string_generator.py", line 10, in <genexpr>
    c for c in map(urandom, repeat(1)) if c in chars
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes
```

I am pretty sure it's the iteration over the map function causing the TypeError, but I haven't been able to figure out how to convert it to a string or really any other solution. I'd appreciate any help or ideas a lot.

Comment: I think you need to cast `c` in your generator expression to a string:
`char_gen = (c for c in map(urandom, repeat(1)) if str(c) in chars)`

Comment: Sorry, You actually need to call `c.decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was mixing `bytes` and `str` values. Ensuring that everything is in bytes makes it work because `urandom` returns bytes.

```py
# Encode the concatenated strings into a byte string
chars = (string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation).encode()

char_gen = (c for c in map(urandom, repeat(1)) if c in chars)

# Use an empty byte string to join the generated bytes 
pswd_text = b''.join(islice(char_gen, None, string_len))
```

You can always call `pswd_text.decode()` to get a unicode string (`str`).

Comment: That works! I almost hate to ask, but can you explain a bit what's going on here?

Comment: Give me a sec, I've got a cleaner solution that will make more sense. It's just the old problem of mixing unicode strings and byte strings in python.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more clear and direct.